# Using multitouch on Macbook Trackpad with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, macbook, touchpad

I recently removed Mac OSX from my late 2008 Aluminum Macbook and installed Windows 7 (64 bit) instead. Upon booting it up, I realized that the trackpad did not work the same way it did when I had been using Mac OSX.

I can only click with one finger, two or more does nothing. I cannot scroll with two fingers. Basically, all the multitouch functionality is gone. How can I get this fixed?

Comment: The correct way would have been from the BootCamp installer... but you're totally stuck if you have trashed the Mac OS entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I did trash it entirely, I didn't really think the process through. If I hadn't trashed it, though, how could I have done it?

Comment: It would have installed automatically with the BootCamp setup.

Comment: I reinstalled Mac OS, and used bootcamp to create a Windows partition. However, it's telling me bootcamp is not supported on my laptop (since it's too old, I assume). Any suggestions, or am I out of luck?

Comment: May wrong version of Boot Camp? You need 4 or 5 depending on what Mac & Win OS you want - see https://support.apple.com/HT205016